# empty a specific column of numbers from the datagridview

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagridviewcolumn

**Question:**

How to empty specific column of numbers from datagridview? (i mean erase the values without header, not delete the column).

for example FROM  [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7qRf.png) TO [THAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewh1t.png), so i dont need to do it manually

**How i created the datagridview:**

i created a database table, with 5 ID's all of datatype "int", i connected the datagridview through DataSource, bindingsource. And when i put values in the table and press button:(button code below)

```
table1BindingSource2.EndEdit();
table1TableAdapter2.Update(database1DataSet8.Table1;
```

It will save the values into DataTable.

For example the first ID in the table is : Konduktivita1[µS_cm-1]

What i think is neccesery is to actually delete the values from DataTable but i dont how to do it.

Comment: You could simply set the values to null or empty string. How you would do that depends on how you are creating the data source in the first place, and if your grid is read only or if it allows edits.

Comment: I created database linked with datagridview using bindingsource and the grid allows edits

Comment: Do you allow edits to the column you want to "erase"? That could be tricky if you don't want them all to update to blank or null when you save changes.

Comment: That sounds as if you are `winforms` as opposed to `wpf` or another UI tier, right? If you would add the corresponding Tag, readers would immediately know what you are talking about I think

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you provided some kind of code, but let's try something like this.

```
var sourceList = dataGridName.ItemsSource as List<sqlTable>; //or whatever your data is called
    foreach (var item in sourceList)
    {
        item.Konduktiva1 = null; // or 0
        
    }
```

Comment: i created a database table, with 5 ID's all of datatype "int", i connected the datagridview through DataSource, bindingsource. And when i put values in the table and press button, it will do :
table1BindingSource2.EndEdit();
                table1TableAdapter2.Update(database1DataSet8.Table1);

For example the first ID in the table is : Konduktivita1[µS_cm-1]